# React Native- Pass Data between Drawer Navigator screens

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, screen

I have an app in which I have a drawer navigator. Because you don't use Buttons you **can't** use

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen', {param: data});`

So how do I pass data from one Drawer Navigator screen to another one?

Answer (score 0):

Create Function Call That Function calls the below line,

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen', {param: data});
```

like this:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import Screen from './Screen'
const drawernav = createDrawerNavigator(
{
Main: { screen: stackNav } 
});
const Drawer = createAppContainer(drawernav)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what you would use in a Stack Navigator, but in a drawer Navigator I can't do it because there are no "onPress" functions I can call that with

Answer (score 0):

You can use onItemPress() for each item in the drawer ,where you can navigate and pass params.

[Official docs on contentOptions for Items](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#contentoptions-for-draweritems.)

Also you can use your  contentComponent for your customise drawer and can add for each individual item for onPress action and pass the params like you want.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use onItemPress() ?

Comment: createDrawerNavigator({
    Home:{screen:Home , contentOptions:{onItemPress({ route, focused })=>{//your navigation and params . navigation.navigate() }}
})

Comment: What is "route, focused" and what do I have to have in the second part after the "=>"

Comment: You can have a look at the official docs : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#contentoptions-for-draweritems

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah I looked at it but I still don't know what "routes, focused" and the second part is ...so basically everything xD